# Check if Javascript contains certain method

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm having a javascript class, that an object is being passed to it, that object is anonymous and changes. I want to check if within the properties of that object there's a matching method name within that class.

Here's code to make it clear:

```js
var Panel = function(obj) {
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (typeOf this[prop] == function) {   // ?? please help with this check
      this[prop](obj[prop]); // call this method with right argument in this case will be this.maxWidth("400px")
    }
  }

  this.maxWidth = function(max_width) {
    document.getElementById(obj["id"]).style.maxWidth = max_width;
  }
}


var myObj = {
  "maxWidth": "400px"
}

var p = new Panel(myObj);
```

Comment: Make it `"function"`. `typeof` (lowercase!) returns a string.

Comment: so... after the above comment, your problem is....

Comment: @Bergi i don't get this solution. Can you please explain?

Comment: change `typeOf this[prop] == function` to `typeof this[prop] === "function"`

Comment: @dandavis that still doesn't work

Comment: @JoeSaad: Also you are creating the method you are looking up in `this` only *after* you've checked for it.

Comment: @Bergi you are right, I changed the location of that method.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected code, you need to use `typeof` not `typeOf` and `function` needs to be wrapped in quotes, as `typeof` returns a string:

```
var Panel = function(obj) {
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (typeof this[prop] == 'function') {   // ?? please help with this check
      this[prop](obj[prop]); // call this method with right argument in this case will be this.maxWidth("400px")
    }
  }

  this.maxWidth = function(max_width) {
    document.getElementById(obj.id).style.maxWidth = max_width;
  };
};


var myObj = {
  "maxWidth": "400px"
};

var p = new Panel(myObj);
```

https://jsbin.com/yemoki/1/edit?js,console

Comment: you are right. This code works after also doing the above mentioned suggestion by adding the method above its call. Here's a link for the code after the changes suggested. Thanks all! https://jsfiddle.net/joeSaad/yavw0uo1/